# Warning 634: Strong type mismatch (type 'bool') in equality or conditional

Tags: c++, assert, lint

```
This is part of my code base 
I am rying to run the below code and getting the warning like below code:

    #define assert_always()         assert(TRUE)

    base::derived(
        uint8 id;
    ){
        switch(id)
        {
        case one:
        ----;
        break;
        case two:
        ----;
        break;
        default:
        assert_always();
        break;
        }
    }

    Warning 634: Strong type mismatch (type 'bool') in equality or conditional  .......

The line number is pointing to `assert_always()` function call. Can you guide me to first to understand and then solve this warning?

I have checked by changing TRUE to true but stil having the same problem ...

Actually code was like this in c++ :
#define assert_always()

    base::derived(
        uint8 id;
    ){
        switch(id)
        {
        case one:
        ----;
        break;
        case two:
        ----;
        break;
        default:
        assert_always();
        break;
        }
    }

I got the warning Warning 634: Strong type mismatch (type 'bool') in equality or conditional so I introduce
```

## define assert_always()    assert(TRUE)

but still warning came  and after other reply ,modified to

## define assert_always()    assert(true)

```
but still warning is there ...I am not getting all the exact reason behind this ...
```

the ----; line are some functionality ...and mentioned code is in C++

Comment: What is TRUE? what are the ----; lines and is this C or C++

Answer (score 4):

What is `TRUE`?

Try it with the actual Boolean constant:

```
#define assert_always assert(false)
```

Also note that `assert(true)` will *never* assert, since the expression (literally) is true.

Comment: I have edited my post after your reply  ...please just look into that

Answer (score 0):

Use true C++ bool type:

```
assert(true)
```

instead of `TRUE`

But it won't do what you want (assert always). assert(false) will.

Comment: I have edited my post after your reply  ...please just look into that

Comment: Is it Lint error? Try to construct minimal example where it occurs, but with full code and Lint options.